# multiple ng-repeat is no work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

using angularJs, code like this:

```
 <td ng-repeat="i in data.numArr3">
    <select ng-model="num{{i}}"  ng-change="change()">
        <option  ng-repeat="item in data.numArr3" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

controller:

```
$scope.data = {
    numArr2: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],

    numArr3: ["-0",-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10], 
    }
```

It won't work;
I just want to create 11 selects, which have same options.
thanks~

Comment: *"it won't work"* ... that is not a problem statement that tells anyone anything of value

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `controllerAs`

change your controller to `ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"`

access scope variable like this

```
ng-repeat="i in vm.data.numArr3"
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
var vm = this;
vm.num ={}
vm.data = {
    numArr2: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],

    numArr3: ["-0",-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10], 
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
<table>
  <tr>
   <td ng-repeat="i in vm.data.numArr3">
    <select ng-model="vm.num[i]"  ng-change="vm.change()">
        <option  ng-repeat="item in vm.data.numArr3" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```